# android eclipse lock screen app full screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

before anything sorry for my bad English.

i search a lot this site but not found my answer.sorry

i make a lock-screen app.(for android 4.0+)
so i make a "**Service**" that call a "**Broadcast Receiver**".
in the "**Broadcast Receiver**" as what happen :

if(SCREEN_OFF) else if(SCREEN_ON) else if(BOOT_COMPLETED))

i start my main activity (my main lock-screen application).

until this moment all thing work perfectly and device lock and unlock correctly.

---

**but there is some problem.**

**1** : how to set my app as default lock-screen app?

**2** : when device is lock if i press "*home button*","*back button*","*recent button*", i transfer to home screen and lock-screen go to recent like another normal application and i access to device without any security.

**2-1** : as you now in android 4.0+ we can not override "*Home button*".

---

**my solution  for problem 2:**
i search in developer.google and find below method for draw a "view" over other apps with this permission : `<uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`

```
 windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

      WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
              PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

     windowManager = (WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

     LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     LinearLayout mTopView = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_lock, null);

     windowManager.addView(mTopView, params);
```

**but this method only draw my xml file over other apps.
i want this for my activity.**

---

i use this FLAGs but button still working :(

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

---

please say , if you have any idea how to make this activity over other apps.

please help me to solve this problem
thank you very much.